# Papers about algorithms for finding solutions of an underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity

Are there any papers about algorithms for finding solutions to an underdetermined linear system? Also, what's the known time complexity for finding solutions to an underdetermined system (if the solutions exist)?

It would be appreciated if anyone can give me some references.

Comment: Underdetermined **linear** systems ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: A fast algorithm for computing minimal-norm solutions to underdetermined systems of linear equations,
Mark Tygert